# Firebase - "does not have storage.objects.get access to"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

Im using the Google Cloud Platform to copy my firebase storage to my local machine.

I have been following the instruction:

[Firebase Storage - How to setup a backup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419175/firebase-storage-how-to-setup-a-backup?rq=1)

Im getting the following AccessDenied Issue:

AccessDeniedException: 403 HttpError accessing https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/dalt=media: response: <{'status': '403', 'content-length': '170', 'expires': 'Sat, 28 Dec 2019 16:49:14 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnnALIyhTjW1hm11c3Pf8PJY3A', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'date': 'Sat, 28 Dec 2019 16:49:14 GMT', 'alt-svc': 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43",h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q049=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}>, content

The same account was used to set up Firebase and Google Cloud Platform, but its saying that the email which was used for both setups doesnot have access to download the images.

The tutorial im following has a step:

> In order for Google Cloud Utils to download the files that were
>   uploaded with Firebase permissions you need to give your account
>   Firebase Privileges. Go to the IAM page and select your email address
>   you signed into cloud init with. In the list of available permissions
>   you need to select Firebase Rules System from the Other category.

Im not sure how to perform this step. This could be the issue, can someone give more details on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the way to do this is:

1. In order for Google Cloud Utils to download the files that were uploaded with Firebase permissions you need to give your account Firebase Privileges. Go to the IAM
2. Make sure your on the members tab, and click on the +Add button
3. In the new members field, enter the email you used to set up GCP and in the drop down for select role, select Firebase Admin
4. Now the following should work Run the gutil command `gsutil -m cp -R gs://<bucket_name> .`

Answer (score 1):

> In the list of available permissions you need to select **Firebase Rules
>   System** from the **Other** category.

This was changed to:

> In the list of available permissions you need to select **Firebase Rules
>   System** from the **Firebase Products** category.